# За что еще знаки? Что-то поменялось?

Tags: дефект, статус-так-задумано, очередь-проверок, знаки

Только что [получил](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/83/steward?userid=337540) еще <s>три</s> 10 золотых знаков ревизор за очереди, где я уже раньше сделал 1k проверок. Почему? Это баг или что-то еще поменялось? Смотрю такое же произошло с некоторыми другими аккаунтами, [например](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/178576/aleksandr-barakin?tab=activity).

Comment: А я 2 получил)))

Comment: @Qwertiy Я девять XD

Comment: @Qwertiy О, десятая XD

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[статус-так-задумано](/questions/tagged/%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%83%d1%81-%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%b4%d1%83%d0%bc%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%be)

Как выяснилось, так и [задумано](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/360279/steward-badge-can-now-be-awarded-multiple-times-backfill-details). Кратко:

Теперь этот знак вручается многократно — за каждую тысячу проверок в каждой из очередей.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/119160/discussion-on-answer-by-victor-vosmottor-------).