# Нужна ли нам "золотая лихорадка" в незаполненых очередях проверок набиванием их счётчика аудитами?

Tags: обсуждение, очередь-проверок, аудит

С недавнего времени можно [получить золотой знак многократно](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/11337) за каждую тысячу проверок в каждой из очередей проверок. То есть, достаточно в течении 50-ти дней выполнить 20 проверок в одной из очередей и кубочек «Последние достижения» вверху правее "озолотится".

Если в очереди действительно проверок достаточно, например, в [Голоса за закрытие](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/close) или [Сообщения низкого качества](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts), то всё в порядке, о них речь не идёт.

А если проверок в очереди не хватает, и даже отслеживая очередь весь день, 20-ти не набрать, как же тут быть?
Яркий пример тому [Голоса за переоткрытие](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/reopen), или менее яркий - [Предлагаемые правки](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits).

На помощь приходят аудиты (или проверка бдительности). Частыми провалами этих аудитов можно провоцировать сайт посылать следующие аудиты всё чаще и чаще, как итог — можно где-то за 15-20 мин. выполнить дневную норму проверок 20 сообщ. эффективно не выполнив ни одной реальной проверки. О проверке бдительности тут и речи быть не может, потому что участникам, часто проваливающим аудиты, заведомо известно, что полученное из очереди сообщение не что иное, как очередной аудит.

Вопросы по этому поводу уже возникали у ряда участников, например у [@Danis](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/57176121#57176121):

> мне почему-то не верится, что в очереди на переоткрытие было целых 20 вопросов, как вы сделали 20 проверок?

Аналогичные вопросы задавались и в общем чате (сообщения не нашёл, потому что не помню точно, кто их задавал). Тут надо отметить, что это поведение могут наблюдать только участники с реп. >= 10к, так как только им доступна [полная история в очередях проверок](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools), другими словами, большинство участников не могут ничего или мало чего заметить.

Как сообщество относится к практике получения золотых знаков за счёт набивания счётчика проверок спровоцированными аудитами? И почему модераторы, обладая инструментом [лишения участников привилегии доступа к очередям проверок](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/review-suspensions), не применяют его?

Comment: Можно какой-то "утешительный" инкремент сделать в безрыбные дни если человек зашел в проверки, вместо фейковой проверки бдительности. И сделать какой-то порог/баланс реальных и утешительных очков. Так будет больше уважения к стремящимся набить медалей.

Comment: А модераторы серьезно не применяют лишение доступа к очередям проверок? Это ооооочень странно.

Comment: @AntonMenshov Нет, мне случаи блокировок очередей проверок не известны (у нас, на SO случалось).

Comment: @PavelGrishaev Не совссем понятно, как  "утешительный" инкремент должен работать.

Comment: @0xdb Я то сам проверки не делаю, считаю их неоднозначными в большинстве случаев. Аудиты же случаются, судя по описанию в этом посту, и наращивают недостающее число проверок. Вот можно нарастить просто так. Показать типа есть что проверять, и там сообщение "спасибо что вы такой хороший". Это не очень-то отличается от кучи плюсов за ёлки и в целом на фоне игровой составляющей вполне приемлемо наверное.

Comment: О, спасибо, не знал. Пошел фармить золотой кубок (шутка)

Comment: @PavelGrishaev На утешительный инкремент тут же вешается скрипт, который буедт автоматом заходить вместо человека.

Comment: Как по мне, за аудит счетчик вообще не должен повышаться.

Comment: @ЮрийКозлов Да, но существующую логику сайта разработчики менять не будут. Если аудиты когда-то [включили](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/1451/217579), то их скорее всего можно выключить, это может было бы и лучше.

Comment: Это просто накрутка ИМХО. Хотя правила она едва ли нарушает... Это исключительно дело проверяющего.

Хотя мне это не нравится. По-моему это бессмысленно, и накрученные знаки — кому они нужны?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Может быть немного не в тему, но выскажусь. Так сказать, взгляд со стороны сравнительно нового участника, у которого пока нет значка ни за одну из очередей проверок *(пока что мне доступна только очередь первых сообщений)*.

На самом деле я вот хочу получить значок, но получить его сложно. Проблема не в количестве проверок, которые надо выполнить, а в том, что **проверять элементарно нечего**. В топе проверок за день и в топе проверок за всё время всегда одни и те же люди. Чтобы выполнить 20 проверок в день, приходится действительно сидеть и ловить проверки.

Разумеется, глупо винить участников, которые уже получили свои значки и теперь получают их во второй или десятый раз, из-за чего мне не достаются проверки, и я не могу получить даже первый значок :) Но, возможно, если бы значки были доступны для получения только единожды, то такой ситуации не было бы или она была бы менее выражена.

Таким образом я думаю, что справедливей было бы давать значки только один раз. Хотя вреда от сложившейся ситуации не так много.

**P.S.:** да, я знаю, что от значков нет никакой пользы, но мне они нравятся. Нет, другие участники не виноваты в том, что у них много значков за проверки, а у меня мало. Я говорю лишь о той ситуации, которую вижу сам. И высказываюсь о том, чем она плоха лично для меня.

Comment: От майнеров одни проблемы, это точно :)

Comment: @αλεχολυτ Были майнеры, стали золотоискатели.

Answer (score 6):

Вообще, как [пишут на MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/158678/339911), провалы аудитов должны приводить к блокировке доступа к очередям проверок. Если при соблюдении условий, описанных на MSE, блокировки не происходит, то это основание для публикации соответствующего баг-репорта.

В любом случае, если система не может по какой-либо причине (баг, отключена опция, функционал не реализован...) отреагировать на сомнительные действия пользователя, в игру должны вступать модераторы, чтобы донести до пользователя информацию о недопустимости систематической накрутки. И применить санкции к злостным нарушителям в ручном режиме.

Comment: Я уже пробовал в одной из очередей 20 провалов подряд, и ничего, ни система, ни модераторы, не блокируют, только аудиты посыпались как мана небесная. Отмечать как принятый, или подождём денёк-два?

Comment: @0xdb принятие или не принятие - это только вам решать. Обычно это говорит только об одном: автор для себя вопрос закрыл с соответствующим результатом. При этом, мне кажется, что логическим продолжением должна быть публикация баг-репорта, о том, что блокировки доступа к очередям не происходит. И лучше бы это сформулировать так, чтобы опубликовать на MSE, а не на нашей мете, где (более-менее оперативной) связи с SOтрудниками практически никакой уже не осталось.

Comment: Баг-репорт написать конечно можно, проблема в вопросе этим решена не будет. Можно и не проваливать аудиты, будет значительно дольше, а результат тотже - 20 проверок в день, из них ни одной реальной.