# Аудиты, очереди проверок и что происходит с контролем качества

Tags: обсуждение, очередь-проверок, модерация, инструменты-модератора, аудит

Последние пару недель я внимательно следил за статистикой [в очередях проверок](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review) и обнаружил много интересных и странных для моего понимания моментов.

Главная задача очередей проверок — это выборочное улучшение вопросов, ответов и правок, которые наиболее вероятно нуждаются в помощи (первые вопросы и ответы, правки от еще неопытных пользователей, вопросы на закрытие переоткрытие). Однако кто будет контролировать проверяющих? Для этого предусмотрены два варианта: автоматические аудиты и ручной контроль модераторами (и, иногда, участниками с высокой репутации).

Я буду склонен утверждать, контроль за очередями проверок на *Stack Overflow на русском* практически отсутствует. И это вызывает (как минимум) следующие проблемы:

- автоматические аудиты постоянно проваливаются ([пример 1](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/11514/%D0%9D%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BC-%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%85%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%B2-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%8F%D1%85-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BC-%D0%B8%D1%85#comment49509_11518), сегодняшние провалы [раз](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/655928), [два](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/655927) от одного участника-топа очередей проверок, сегодняшние провалы [раз](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/656061), [два](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/656050) от другого участника-топа очередей проверок) — и это постоянное явление. Никаких санкций за провал аудитов не предусмотрено, и инструмент НЕ ИСПОЛЬЗУЕТСЯ и просто формален.
- [имеем "золотую лихорадку"](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/11514/337980) с набиванием счетчика проверок
- если внимательно почитать историю [комнаты чата по очередям проверок](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/119134/), то у участников возникают претензии (пока, воздержусь от комментариев по конкретике) по использовании автокликера, некачественной работе и т.д.

Итого:

- очереди проверок не очень-то хорошо работают на данный момент.
- **имеющиеся инструменты: автоматические аудиты и ручная блокировка очередей проверок модераторами по неизвестной мне причине [не используются](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/59244609#59244609) [по назначению.](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/59244656#59244656)**

Вопрос (как к сообществу, так и к модераторам):

- почему эти уже имеющиеся инструменты не работают?

<sub>NB: данный вопрос не касается напрямую темы автокликеров. Однако, ручная блокировка некачественных "проверяльщиков" и автоматические аудиты могут косвенно решить и эту задачу. Степ бай стап.</sub>

Comment: Очередь на закрытие в принципе не работает, большинство попадающих в неё вопросов не набирают необходимых четырёх-пяти решений (ни за закрытие, ни даже за оставление открытым), и через неделю голоса просто сгорают

Comment: @andreymal, это уж точно совсем другая история (основная причина — малолюдность в очереди проверок).

Comment: @andreymal на некоторых сайтах снизили порог до 3, может у нас тоже стоит?

Comment: @PashaPash о, если так реально можно, то наверное было бы хорошо, я давно об этом подумывал. Правда, тогда увеличится частота ложноположительных закрывашек 

Comment: @andreymal точно можно, даже на основном so сейчас 3: https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/close-questions

Answer (score 6):

продублирую (с дополнением) то, что уже писал в чате по поводу множественных провалов аудитов:

насколько мне известно, побудить движок выдавать больше аудитов после провалов аудита, можно в следующих очередях: правки, переоткрытие, первые вопросы.

очереди, в которых, кажется, это тоже происходит: низкокачественные и закрытие. в остальных очередях (первые и запоздалые ответы) такого поведения у движка нет.

да, в упомянутых очередях существует «дискриминация» для новичков (с репутацией, вроде бы, ниже 10000): они получают временный бан на проверки, если совершили несколько провалов аудита.

если такой же бан будут получать все, независимо от репутации, то:

1. исчезнет «дискриминация».
2. у пользователей с высокой репутацией исчезнет стимул к накрутке голосов (методом провалов аудита) в этих очередях.
3. возможно, это как-то оздоровит сложившуюся в данный момент ситуацию.

---

иной предлагаемый мной вариант исправления ситуации: синхронизировать алгоритмы появления новых аудитов во всех очередях. т.е., чтобы в очередях правок, переоткрытий и первых вопросов **не генерировались** бесконечное количество раз всё новые и новые аудиты как реакция на провал аудита. предполагаемые последствия аналогичны вышеизложенным трём пунктам.

Comment: синхронизация алгоритмов - требует внимание разработчиков и, значит, имеет малую вероятность быть воплощенным. При небольшом количестве участников очередей проверок — автоматика бана и ручной бан — не самая сложная задача.

Comment: @AntonMenshov, с точки зрения внимания разработчиков первое моё предложение ничем принципиальным от второго не отличается.

Answer (score 3):

##### Причина создавшейся ситуации

Получение пунктов за выполнение проверок сообщений, полученных из очередей проверок, было задумано разработчиками для привлечения участников к модерации сайтов SE. Своего рода «игрофикация», схожая с репутацией за вопросы/ответы. Не зря же было снято ограничение на получение золотых медалей за только первую 1000 проверок.

Но задуманная «игрофикация» *не работает*, если очереди проверок большую часть времени пустые. Для сравнения, в очереди «Голоса за закрытие» поведения, затронутого в вопросе, не наблюдается, потому что она постоянно полная.

##### Как наиболее эффективно изменить создавшуюся ситуацию

Предложение уже [было озвучено](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/11518): *И применить санкции к злостным нарушителям в ручном режиме*.

То есть, отстранить в ручном режиме *всех участников*, замеченных в манипуляциях с очередями проверок, от проверок в этих очередях *бессрочно*. Что такая возможность есть, сомнений нет, о ней даже в [справке упомянуто](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/review-suspensions).

Оставить, как исключение, «авгиеву конюшню» - «Голоса за закрытие».

##### Преимущественные стороны предложения

Проверки сообщений возможно проводить и вне очередей проверок. Поэтому, о преимуществе предложения выше пока выскажусь субъективно (т.е., от своего лица): ожидаемое снижение кол-ва проверенных сообщений за день восполнится несравненным повышением внимания *самому сообщению*, а не «пунктикам, медалькам и фантикам», в конечном итоге, за его проверку полученным. Другими словами, переход количества в качество будет очевидным преимуществом.

Answer (score 2):

##### Очереди и отношение к ним

Насколько понимаю по прошлому опыту и обсуждениям с другими участниками, происходит примерно так:

- относительно новые участники верят в систему / ее обещания - и если идут в проверки, то поначалу выполняют их ответственно
- когда участник приобретает осознание того что пользовательская модерация на SO "сломана", он следует по одному из трех путей:

  - продолжает выполнять проверки столь же тщательно и честно, но с уже другой мотивацией (пытаясь что-то изменить) - то есть, уже не в согласии с двуличной системой, а вопреки ей
  - вовсе перестает выполнять проверки, решив что тщетно тратить на них свое время (т.к. большинство, которому сложившаяся ситуация выгодна или привычна - в итоге "победит", так или иначе)
  - продолжает выполнять проверки, но со снижением участия "утилитарной морали" в этом процессе (кто за золото, кто в режиме ритуала - цель не суть важна, важно то что это перестает быть *проверкой*)

##### Аудит не работает, и это хорошо

Сама концепция аудита, чисто логически, имеет смысл когда эффективность разбора очередей опережает их наполнение.
У нас же, ситуация такова что голосуют за все подряд - а количество желающих в этом копаться, похоже, не возрастает. Иначе говоря, дефицит проверяющих. Это не та ситуация, в которой разумно их сокращать, даже при низком качестве проверок.

Если аудит начнет работать в полную силу, с блокировками, то пользовательская модерация ruSO может сломаться еще сильнее чем в ее текущем состоянии (трудно представить, но все же). Выбирая между "золотой лихорадкой" и усилением невозможности закрыть/переоткрыть, меньшим злом видится "золотая лихорадка": ведь самой базе знаний от этих накрученных знаков в принципе ни холодно ни жарко, лишь бы соотношение сигнал/шум в голосах было приемлемым.
Тут гораздо важнее само явление накрутки аудитом, а возникло оно видимо из-за того что...

##### ...качество - это миф

Говоря о ситуации с очередями, трудно игнорировать состояние упадка с качеством (в целом). Кто-то назовет причиной слишком жесткие правила SO, но правила сами по себе не имеют силы: силой их наделяют те, кто этими правилами руководствуется/оправдывается при действиях по отношению к другим. И поэтому, очень многое зависит от целей и мотивации участников.

Как это связано с очередями проверок? Самым непосредственным образом: для работающего контроля качества (успешных голосований, и проверок проверяющих), нужны определенные условия, а прежде всего **общее понимание о качестве**. По факту же, такое понимание общим не является - показателями этого выступают такие местные нормы как голосование наобум и/или по стадному инстинкту, единоличные "слепые" закрытия вопросов, и малая информированность новых участников. Все это создает условия в которых качественным называется либо то что субъективно нравится, либо совсем уж недостижимый идеал. В таких условиях возможно контролировать "войну предпочтений" или накрутку знаков, но не качество. И вполне закономерно, что некоторые теряют для себя цель и смысл проверок. Виноваты в этом не люди или технические возможности, а именно условия, которые приводят к потере мотивации и разобщению.

##### Что с этим нужно делать

Ничего.
Сообщество само создает здесь то положение дел, которое каждый участник по-своему оценивает - но давайте взглянем правде в глаза: суждения отдельных людей из толпы не определяют ее поведение. Регулированием администрация может заниматься, только вот она на enSO (которому до нас дела нет) - а здесь управление похоже отсутствует, царит самотек.
Поэтому, имхо, все эти мета-обсуждения лишь иллюзия решений и прогресса: нет другого выбора, кроме как дать сообществу развиваться его естественным путем. Если все же хочется что-то сделать, то эффективнее воздействовать на причины, а не на симптомы: объяснять новичкам, за что их "гнобят", помогать уточнениями, вносить правки, обращать внимание на социальное поведение тех кто выбирается представлять ruSO перед рядовыми участниками - все это может дать надежду на изменение курса сообщества от "закрыть!/заминусовать!/ограничить!" к действительному повышению качества. Когда голосование будет использоваться осознанно, тогда и об аудите будет смысл подумать.

Если обязательно надо (или очень хочется) что-то подкрутить в качестве решения ситуации с халявой, то предлагаю вместо ввода блокировок по автоаудиту, отредактировать условия получения значков. И только если эта менее радикальная мера не даст эффекта, уже переходить к привычно-негативному решению через блокировки и прочие наказания неверных.

Comment: Не согласен как минимум с одним аспектом. Теза: у нас недостаточно проверяющих, значит блокировать доступ и контролировать качество проверок не нужно, а то вообще все сломается.

Comment: @AntonMenshov, согласие и не требуется... Ведь в тексте я не навязываю свою точку зрения, а всего лишь обращаю внимание участников на нерациональность доламывания пользовательской модерации во имя перекрытия халявы со знаками (чисто косметическими). Кто считает значки более важными, волен поставить минус ответу. Если же этот коммент о несогласии без указания на ошибки / предложения альтернатив мне следовало понимать как претензию «ты должен был поддержать меня, а не рассуждать тут!» - то прошу прощения, я решил что мнения допустимы увидев метку [обсуждение]... но удалять ответ пока не стану.

Comment: Я понятия не имею о чем вы. Мнения не просто допустимы — они обязательно нужны. Из вашего поста я выделил одну мысль, с которой радикально не согласен - и решил конкретно об этом написать. Прошу прощения, что вас это не интересует и\или вызывает такую реакцию.

Comment: Далее. Если детально развернуть мою мысль, то речь не о значках. а вообще о качестве проверок. Если на качество проверок не обращать внимания (аудит и ручная блокировка - лишь инструменты), то все пойдет в тар-тарары (как оно и скатывается, на мой взгляд). Если их использовать по назначению - то тоже может скатиться, но мне кажется, что все же стоит попробовать забить гвоздь молотком, даже если и гвоздь ржавый, и молоток хрупкий.

Comment: @AntonMenshov, все-таки я предлагаю согласие/несогласие выражать через кнопки ▲▼, чтобы другим участникам было проще читать замечания и предложения по существу, не отвлекаясь на реакции. А желание поднять качество проверок (из которого возник вопрос) и ввести карательные меры, мне вполне понятно - но как участник желающий вернуться в очереди, ратую именно за это: за сокращение "мусора" в очередях (из-за проблемы качества и как следствие необузданного голосования)... конечно, совсем нерадостной видится перспектива еще большего замусоривания, которое практически гарантируется вводом блокировок((