# Как насчет разгрести очередь проверок?

Tags: обсуждение, очередь-проверок

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Может навалимся и разгребем [это безобразие](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review)? А то как не гляну число "нуждается в проверке" все растет и растет.

Я бросал эту затею на 600 в очереди, скоро круглая 1000 уже будет

**UPD** Спасибо, кто принимает участие в данном мероприятии. Осталось около 300. Совсем немного. Остальным с достаточным количеством репутации, присоединяйтесь!

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А зачем? Само понятие "закрытие вопроса" не имеет смысла

Comment: Ну, может, знаки кому нужны золотые?=) Мне если честно, просто глаза мазолит

Comment: Давненько значит Вы туда не заходили. У меня там счетчик в разы меньше. У каждого он свой в зависимости от обработанных записей.

Comment: @МихаилРебров не уверен, но если это действительно так, то я точно умываю руки и больше туда не заглядываю

Comment: Цифра там большая, потому что она за день на полсотни как минимум пополняется (с учетом проверок) и потому что там много неоднозначных вопросов, которые с одной стороны закрывать жалко, с другой стороны ответственность за публикацию таких вопросов не каждый возьмет. Вот они там и болтаются. От того цифра и растет

Comment: @Dmitry `не уверен` - если Вы про счетчик, то `да`. Там цифра учитывает то, сколько вы обработали и показывает то, сколько осталось именно Вам. Но если Вы туда давно не заходили - то она близка к общему количеству необработанных записей.

Comment: Да кому оно всё нужно?))

Comment: @АлексейШиманский и вот уже эта тема https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/11514/209304 совсем не актуальна)

Comment: Я не имею доступ к "Голосам за закрытие", и у меня показывает, что в очереди 376 постов, а не 300. При чём мне-то показывается реальное число сообщений, ведь вам показывается меньше (т.к есть вопросы, которые вы уже проверили, а они ещё не закрыты или не выкинуты из очереди)

Comment: @Зонтик _"Я не имею...."_ но докопаться до цифр вам принципиально, порядок верен и идите уже своей дорогой.

Comment: Может быть, меня там нехватает?

Answer (score 2):

Я считаю, что разгрести "голоса за закрытие" всё-таки стоит.

#### Зачем?

1. Решить ситуацию с вопросами, которые сейчас находятся в очереди;
2. Чтобы как только вопрос попадал в очередь, ему оказывалось внимание. Так, например, происходит во всех остальных очередях.
3. Чтобы не было [такого](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12426/%d0%a2%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b3%d1%83-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d1%8f%d1%8e%d1%82-%d1%83%d0%b6%d0%b5-%d0%b4%d0%b2%d0%b5-%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b8?noredirect=1&lq=1);

#### Какова ситуация сейчас?

Очередь уже разгребают. Ещё два месяца назад там было 800 сообщений, а сейчас счётчик перешёл отметку `500`: в очереди `488` сообщений.

К сожалению, я не могу ещё принять участие в этой работе (репутации не хватает), но когда наберу `3К`, обязательно этим займусь `=)`. Может, к тому времени, очередь и разгребут, и сообщений в ней будет столько, сколько сейчас в "сообщениях низкого качества" (`10` - `40` штук).

Но проверять всё равно надо, а то опять начнётся... Ну и не стоит забывать, что **проверка нужна не ради проверки, а ради отведения внимания к сообщениям, которые его требуют**. А то сейчас куча сообщений выходят из очереди (голоса за закрытие и тревоги сгорают, вот и нет вопроса в очереди).