# Возможность повышения минимального рейтинга для привилегии "Спрашивать"

Tags: обсуждение, предложение

SO постепенно превратился в сайт школьных заданий и лабораторных работ. Зайдя на вкладку "Вопросы->Новые", вопросов не из разряда "памагите сделать дз" будет меньшинство. Такие вопросы быстро минусуются и блокируются(удаляются и тп), но тем не менее, это замыливает поиск тех вопросов, на которые ты ищешь ответ или выбор тех, на которые ты мог бы дать ответ. Более того, это отнимает время администрации и других участников ресурса. А при удалении вопроса, новичок может не понять что вообще произошло. Вы сами знаете, что часто вопросы дизлайкают вообще без объяснения причины(даже если эта причина реально есть).

В связи с этим у меня предложение : **"Обсудить возможность повышения минимального рейтинга для привилегии "Спрашивать"(если её возможно вынести отдельно). "** Таким образом, человек, который хочет получить ответ, сначала должен немного помочь SO полезным ответом, правкой и тп. Но, неопытному человеку, скорее всего, такого будет добиваться не легко (и даже не быстро), поэтому предлагаю вдобавок ввести тестирование, за которое человек с рейтингом 1 может получить какой-то рейтинг, которого достаточно, чтобы задавать вопросы. В тестировании нужно будет ответить на простые вопросы о правилах сайта и показать, что человек умеет оформлять вопрос и код в нём(НЕ КАРТИНКОЙ!!!).

Пример вопроса из такого тестирования:

Выберите правильную постановку вопроса:
а) Не работает задача, вот код.
б) Придумайте решение, вот задача
в) Вот такое условие, вот мой код. Я не понимаю, почему на 13 строке происходит так, а не иначе. Этим кодом в 13 строке я хотел сделать вот это потому,что ... Я пробовал еще это и читал это, но решение не подходит.

Так, мы сможем повысить качество вопросов(дадим какое-то представление о работе ресурса прям на опыте), помочь новичкам разобраться с правилами и призовём их к внимательности и отсеим тех, кто не готов тратить силы и время на то, чтобы разобраться с вопросом.

На данный момент, насколько я понимаю, единственный инструмент, который это регулирует - проверка первого вопроса другими участниками.Может быть есть еще механизмы, о которых я не знаю. Но, как мы все видим, их работу необходимо улучшить.

Я поднял эту тему потому, что я не против вопросов из домашек, я готов помочь человеку разобраться, если он этого хочет. Если человек говорит, что не может разобраться в конкретной теме, пробовал такие решения, приводит пример, нормально оформляет вопрос, то даже если этот вопрос из учебной программы, то помочь ему следует, я считаю. Но ребята, которые пишут "помогите с задачей на циклы" и просто прикрепляют условие в теле вопроса просто дискредитируют любые учебные и простые вопросы и отнимают время тех пользователей ресурса, которые уделяют ему некоторое время на регулярной основе.

Comment: Это происходит не первый год и не сейчас это началось. Так всегда было, так есть, так всегда будет.

Comment: Учебные вопросы без попыток решения ЗАКРЫВАЮТСЯ через очередь проверок. Если не ошибаюсь, то вы можете поставить тревогу на вопросе с указанием причины "`необходимо улучшить`" > "`Специфичная для сообщества причина`" > "`Учебные задания`"

Comment: Посмотрев на описание причины закрытия, можно понять что данной проблемой уже давно озаботились: `Учебные задания допустимы в качестве вопросов только при условии, что вы пытались решить их самостоятельно перед тем, как задать вопрос. Пожалуйста, отредактируйте вопрос и укажите, что именно вызвало у вас трудности при решении задачи. Например, приведите код, который вы написали, пытаясь решить задачу`

Comment: @МихаилРебров суть вопроса не в том что я возмущен новичками, а в том, чтобы улучшить ресурс, добавив тестирование. Если эта проблема существует уже давно, то почему бы её не решить

Comment: А про что два моих вышестоящих комментария? Вопросы про которые вы пишете модерируются и закрываются, что вы ещё хотите сделать?

Comment: Чувак, забей. Я лично минусую и голосую закрыть. На ruSO стало очень мало активных людей, которые отвечают и следят за порядком....очень мало... раньше нас было много ..... поэтому сейчас просто нет людей чтобы этот мусор грести (это одна из причин почему на соседний вопрос https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/12211/191482  я написал - а yabu оно надо :D)....поэтому какие меры не принимай, сейчас этого барахла будет как на любой помойке. А заниматься этим (увеличением репы, всякие тестирования и пр.) никто из разрабов  не будет..

Comment: @МихаилРебров хочу вести тестирование, я же писал выше) Все те меры, что есть сейчас, очевидно не помогают.
Я согласен с вами что это не первый год и поэтому предлагаю решение.
Они закрываются через очередь проверок тем самым отнимая время у других участников.Пока вопросы висят они засоряют поиск,а после удаления новый участник так и останется без вопроса, а с высокой долей вероятности ещё и не поймёт что произошло.
Еще раз подчеркну, что я не хочу обсудить проблему, я предлагаю её решить

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, вы как более опытный участник можете сейчас посоветовать "забить" и скорее всего даже будете правы в какой-то проекции ситуации. Но я предлагаю решение, с ним можно делать что угодно. Тем не менее, даже если оно никому не нужно сейчас,я уверен, что когда-нибудь оно пригодится :D
Тем не менее кол-во голосов "Переоткрыть" и некоторая активность указывает на то, что моё мнение разделяют еще немало людей)

Comment: @SpaceResearcher Просто для решения проблемы обычно есть сообщество, которое  в массе оперативно это всё режет. Этот механизм был издревле придуман и работал (во всяком случае на enSO с этим проблем нет). Разрабы сейчас озабочены бОльшими проблемами: какие значочки ещё в UI повесить, где UTF8 выползает и какие бы шляпы на НГ нарисовать на winterbash2022 xDDD   ..... ЗЫ. предлагать надо тогда на meta.stackexchange.com  .... там они рассматривают предложения.

Comment: ну я ткнул переоткрыть, просто так, а чоб нет xDDD