# Тревогу не проверяют уже две недели

Tags: обсуждение, очередь-проверок, модерация, тревоги

19 февраля этого года поставил тревогу, и она всё ещё не проверена:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Чем занимаются модераторы?

**Update**:
19 марта того же года тревога устарела...

Comment: Тревоги типа "является дубликатом" сложнее всех проверять, ведь для этого нужно понимать, о чём первый вопрос и о чём второй. Вот ещё одна возможная причина. Но честно говоря у меня уже 24 тревоги, которые устарели (то есть модераторы не успели их проверить за месяц), и это как-то уже много.

Comment: https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/12418/191482

Comment: Всем набирать репутацию и активно участвовать в разгребании очереди проверок закрытия вопросов. Модераторы тут не при чем.

Comment: Могу лишь сказать "жиза". Я с февраля начал проявлять активность и за полтора месяца у меня (в данный момент) 157 тревог из которых 25 уже устарели. Активно набираю рейтинг, что бы исправить данную ситуацию...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Тревоги "рекомендовать закрытие" не прилетают в модераторскую очередь в админке.

Вместо этого они живут в [очередях проверок](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review), куда модераторы нечасто заглядывают, ведь предполагается, что по таким вопросам сообщество голосует самостоятельно. Более того, не всем нравится, когда модераторы туда лезут, ведь голос модератора слишком весом.

Стоит ли поднажать в [разгребании этой очереди](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12211/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%82-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%b3%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8-%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d1%8c-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%be%d0%ba) — решать вам.

Comment: А такие тревоги не обрабатываются, потому что в очереди проверок "голоса за закрытиие" происходит  беспорядок (783 сообщения!)

Comment: @Зонтик Что бы это разобрать, одному участнику надо 39 дней. Что бы "закрыть" вопрос надо 5 голосов за закрытие. Надо много активных участников, что бы в 0 вывести эту очередь. А если флагов взводится больше, чем успевают разбирать, вот очередь и растет.

Comment: А где-то описано у нас куда какие тревоги прилетают? Вероятно, если это было бы на виду, текущего вопроса-возмущения не возникло.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ самое близкое — это, наверное, справка по очередям проверок: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/review-close

Comment: Непереведенная почему-то... Можераторы вроде могут справки переводить.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ По-умолчанию - нет. Для этого на странице справки должен стоять специальный флаг в базе.